# Python - efficient data grouping

Tags: python, sorting, memory-efficient

Imagine there are about 200 group presets.
Each group has X number of "items" attached to it. A group can have one item, or 100 items.
Groups often have items with shared names, ie. 
Group_0040 could have item_abcde, item_bcda, item_bcba, and Group_0120 could have item_abcd in common, but 10 others that are not shared with Group_0040.

What is the most efficient way of sorting out lists of X# Groups have the most items in common?
I suppose ideally in the end the data that would be useful to get back would be:

- Sorted from MOST in common to least in common
- List of groups that have these items in common
- The item names.

ie, the most in common might look like:

```
[{'groups': [<Group_0040>, <Group_0041>, <Group_0022, <Group_0076>, <Group_0054>, <Group_0192>, <Group_0017>],
  'items': [<Item_acdb>, <Item_ddbc>, <Item_dddb>, <Item_cbcb>, <Item_acba>, <Item_aaba>]
  }
  ....
]
```

Collecting this data would also have cutoff values - ie, there must be X number of groups in common, and there must be X number of items in common in order for them to be considered.
ie:

getSharedItemGroups(minGroups=4, minItems=5)

Example:

```
class Group(object):
def __init__(self, name):

    self.name = name
    self.items = []

    def addItem(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, name):       
        self.name = name

import random
import string

groups = []
for x in range(200):
    groups.append(Group('Group_{0:04d}'.format(x)))

letters = string.lowercase
for group in groups:
    for i in range(random.randint(0,50)):
        tag = ''
        for c in range(4):
            tag += letters[random.randint(4)]
        group.addItem(Item('item_' + tag)
```

Comment: How would you sort these groups? What's the sort-key?

Comment: Sort the result list? Probably by the Len of the list of groups with matches - for all those that have enough items in common to exceed the minItems parameter